ORA-00902: invalid datatype with EF Core
Please help, I am using EF Core with Oracle (code first) and getting this error after dotnet ef database update and I have no idea what the invalid datatype is:
2024-09-27 16:11:34,098 INFO Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command - Executed DbCommand (73ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE
"RunnerStates" (
    "Id" NUMBER(10) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    "Name" NVARCHAR2(450) NOT NULL,
    "Description" NVARCHAR2(2000),
    CONSTRAINT "PK_RunnerStates" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)';
END;
2024-09-27 16:11:34,121 ERROR Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command - 2024-09-27 16:11:34.121034 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00902: invalid datatype
ORA-06512: at line 2
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00902/
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleFailoverMgrImpl.OnError(OracleConnection connection, CallHistoryRecord chr, Object mi, Exception ex, Boolean bTopLevelCall, Boolean& bCanRecordNewCall)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
2024-09-27 16:11:34.121034 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00902: invalid datatype
ORA-06512: at line 2
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00902/
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleFailoverMgrImpl.OnError(OracleConnection connection, CallHistoryRecord chr, Object mi, Exception ex, Boolean bTopLevelCall, Boolean& bCanRecordNewCall)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)

This is the entity in C#:
public class RunnerState
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public required string Name { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }
}

This is the entity configuration:
public class RunnerStateConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<RunnerState>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<RunnerState> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasKey(s => s.Id);
        builder
            .HasIndex(s => s.Name)
            .IsUnique(true);
        builder
            .HasData(
            new RunnerState
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "AVAILABLE",
                Description = "The runner is available for receiving and executing assigned tasks.",
            },
            new RunnerState
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "UNAVAILABLE",
                Description = "The runner is unavailable for receiving and executing assigned tasks.",
            });
    }
}

I need to add some more details, but I really don't know what else to add. The oracle user/schema is empty, it's the first attempt to update the database after creating an initial migration.
Thank you!
EDIT!!!: I discovered what invalid datatype was: it was a boolean in a different table. As I found out in another SO question Oracle only supports type boolean from 23c and I have to work with 18c. The "problem" is EF Core uses type BOOLEAN in the generated SQL. I also have a solution if anyone is struggling with this, I will write it as an answer to this question.

IDENTITY was added in Oracle 12c. Which database version are you using? What happens when you try to execute this CREATE TABLE directly?

@PanagiotisKanavos What is IDENTITY for? I tried executing the command directly in the database and got PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. The table was created (as well as an index for the PK). Is there an easy way to check Oracle version?

IDENTITY means the key value increments automatically.

I see, thank you, that sounds like it might be a problem for the way I am seeding the data in EF, because I am adding the Id explicitly, but that's what Microsoft's guide said to do here: The primary key value needs to be specified even if it's usually generated by the database.

@Zdeněk If you have an IDENTITY column then when you insert a row either: do not pass a value for that identity column; or pass the value DEFAULT.

Thank you, the official guide for "model seeding" in ef confused me, because they say that even auto-generated columns must be inserted... maybe it just doesn't work for oracle. I really need the id's to be the numbers I want, so I will try disabling this auto-generation. Still it's odd that the error is during create table, not insert...

No, the guide doesn't say that autogenerated columns must be inserted. The column values shouldn't be inserted. The error complains about the CREATE TABLE statement, not the INSERT statement

The solution to the edited question is to tell EF Core to be compatible with an older oracle version like this:
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
    options => options.UseOracle(
            "connection string...",
            x => x.UseOracleSQLCompatibility(OracleSQLCompatibility.DatabaseVersion19)));

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me! :)


"Description" NVARCHAR2(2000),

Would be where I would look first. By default, the max byte size for an NVARCH2 column is 4000 bytes.  So if you are using a UTF-16 character set then its 4 bytes per character which is 8000 bytes for you Description column.  So you either want to explicitly change the max size for you NVARCHAR2 columns in the database itself, change the character set to smaller one, or restrict your "Description" column size to 500 characters in the fluent definition, or using [StringLength(50)] attribute and/or in the table creation sql.
